# Keras Neural Network

Tags: python, keras

I'm learning neural network in python. Here is a basic Neural Network model I've trained in keras:

```
from keras.datasets import imdb
import numpy as np
from keras import models
from keras import layers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
(train_data,train_labels),(test_data,test_labels)=imdb.load_data(num_words=10000)
def vectorize_sequences(sequences,dimension=10000):
    results = np.zeros((len(sequences),dimension))
    for i,sequence in enumerate(sequences):
        results[i,sequence] = 1.  
        return results
x_train = vectorize_sequences(train_data) 
x_test = vectorize_sequences(test_data)  
y_train = np.asarray(train_labels).astype('float32') 
y_test = np.asarray(test_labels).astype('float32')
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(16,activation='relu',input_shape=(10000,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(16,activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
x_val = x_train[:10000]
partial_x_train = x_train[10000:]
y_val = y_train[:10000]
partial_y_train = y_train[10000:]
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(partial_x_train, partial_y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=50, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
history_dict = history.history
history_dict.keys()
history_dict = history.history
loss_values = history_dict['loss']
val_loss_values = history_dict['val_loss']
epochs = range(1, len(loss_values) + 1)
plt.plot(epochs, loss_values, 'bo', label='Training loss')
plt.plot(epochs, val_loss_values, 'b', label='Validation loss')
plt.title('Training and validation loss')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

My train loss is always 0.69 and no change. I try to adjust my batch size and epochs, but it's useless.

[image: This is my picture of train loss]

Comment: Just a typo: `return results` statement in `vectorize_sequences` should not be indented (currently it is part of the `for` loop, therefore after the first iteration it would return so you are only training on one sample!).

Comment: Please add that as the answer , seems spot on.

Comment: Vote up the answer that is helpful